# How migration creates Linkage Disquilibrium

Tags: population-genetics

I want to know how admixture and migration creates linkage disequilibrium? I am reading about it but I really don't quite get it.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine one population is fixed for `A1` at locus `A` and for `B1` at locus `B`. Here is a representation

```
--- A1 --- B1 ---
```

Another population is fixed for `A2` at locus `A` and for `B2` at locus `B`. Here is a representation

```
--- A2 --- B2 ---
```

Further imagine that the recombination rate between loci `A` and `B` is 0 $(r=0)$. Any migration rate will cause some individuals `--- A1 --- B1 ---` to be present in a `--- A2 --- B2 ---` population (and/or vice-versa). So linkage disequilibrium is complete.

If the recombination rate is in between 0 and 0.5, then there will be some level of linkage disequilibrium at equilibrium that can be calculated for a specific demography (incl. migration rate).

Comment: Thank you :) I just have one more question. When you say that A1 is fixed at locus A and B1 at locus B, does that mean that A1 and B1 are in linkage disequilibrium too?

Comment: Linkage disequilibrium is defined for a pair of loci, not for a pair of alleles. It is defined as $D=p_{ab} - p_ap_b$ (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_disequilibrium)). I think the misunderstanding you may have has more to do with the definition of linkage disequilibrium than about the effect of migration and recombination on linkage disequilibrium.  Without migration, each population in the above example is at linkage equilibrium (because there is no variance), while the overall metapopulation is at complete linkage disequilibrium.